# Get all is returning entities which has delete state

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting all entities (3 items). Removing one of them, but not saving. Then getting all again. It is returning me a deleted entity however state of the entity is deleted. Is it something expected? Why it is not returning 2 items? Also, is there any documentation about this?

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var userAsCustomerAndAdmin = context.Set<User>().ToList();//3 items
    context.Set<User>().Remove(userAsCustomerAndAdmin.First());

    var fromTracker = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().ToList();//The state of first item is deleted

    var userAsCustomerAndAdmin2 = context.Set<User>().ToList();//3 items
}
```

**Scenario:** My DbContext life time is longer. I am deleting some entities without saving the context. After that I have some logic that will use `GetAll` and the problem is this logic is doing something with entities that has been deleted from the context.

Comment: [EntityFrameworkCore returning entities that has been marked for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65010305/16606026), this response's point 1 kinda sums up the issue behind such approach.

Comment: Why are you using `context.Set<User>` instead of `context.Users` ?

Comment: @Dai, Hmm, because I don't have context.Users. But I tested and It is working with the same behavior as context.Set<User>

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd call to show 2 entities you can:

1. `SaveChanges(Async)` in between the calls to .ToList(Async)
2. Use `.Set<User>().Local`.

From the official [Accessing Tracked Entities#The Local View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/entity-entries#the-local-view):

> `DbSet<TEntity>.Local` returns a view of locally tracked entities that reflects the current EntityState of those entities. Specifically, this means that:
>
> (...)
>
> Deleted entities are excluded. Note that this is again not the case for normal EF Core queries, since Deleted entities still exist in the database and so are returned by database queries.

And:

> All of this means that DbSet.Local is view over the data that reflects the current conceptual state of the entity graph, with Added entities included and Deleted entities excluded. This matches what database state is expected to be after SaveChanges is called.